# Trying to attach image to mail in my app

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm using the UIimagepicker to choose an image that should be attached to a mail in my ios app. I'm getting this error:

**Warning: Attempt to present < MFMailComposeViewController: 0xc142ab0 > on < ViewControllerMail: 0xb642520 > while a presentation is in progress!**

I'm new to this so.. i gues i'm dismissing the views wrong? I don't even know if the code works to attach the choosen image.

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage, *imageToUse;

// Handle a still image picked from a photo album
if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0)
    == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

    editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                               UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                 UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    if (editedImage) {
        imageToUse = editedImage;
    } else {
        imageToUse = originalImage;
          [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }



    MFMailComposeViewController * mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    // make sure you can make NSData from the object
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToUse, 1.0) mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"what ever you want to call the file"];
    [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];


}
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are presenting the mail composer while the image picker is being dismissed. Make use of the `completion` parameter:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    MFMailComposeViewController * mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    // make sure you can make NSData from the object
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToUse, 1.0) mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"what ever you want to call the file"];
    [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```